# ConstraintLayout gone view behaves in same way as RelativeLayout gone view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

By what I have studied for Constrainlayout -

> For most container classes, marking a widget’s visibility as GONE
>   totally removes it from everything regarding the measurement and
>   layout of the container. It is as if the widget never existed, though
>   you are in position to “add it back in” simply by making it VISIBLE
>   .In Constrainlayout, Widgets that are GONE are treated as having no size (width and height
>   of 0) and having no margins. However, ConstraintLayout will still
>   honor constraints tied to those GONE widgets, taking into account
>   their zero-size and zero-margin status. This allows your constraints
>   to still work, rather than breaking entirely.

But practically I tested with RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout and results are same.Even RelativeLayout honor constraints tied to those GONE widgets.In below code, second textview is aligned at bottom of first textview and third textview is aligned at bottom of second textview.If I make second textview gone,third textview is aligned at bottom of first textview rather than on top of it.This means second's textview         android:layout_below="@id/first" is honoured even after making it Gone.

By what I have studied for Constrainlayout -

> The zero size is non-negotiable. However, it is possible that you may
>   still want margins to be taken into account. To that end, there are
>   attributes like app:layout_goneMarginStart that you can use. As the
>   attribute name suggests, these provide margins to be used when the
>   widget itself is marked as GONE .

But practically I added         app:layout_goneMarginTop="@dimen/dp60" to second Gone textview,but still the position of third textview remained same.

RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:text="first"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:text="second"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"

        android:text="third"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:text="first"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first" 
        android:text="second"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second"

        android:text="third"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add layout_goneMarginTop in third text view. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout